# Apache 2.4 Internal mod_rewrite is not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

I have the following excerpt in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Whether RewriteBase is commented does not appear to have an impact on my problem
# RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) members/$1 [L]
```

The idea is that the pages in `/admin` load from the `/members` directory, since certain features are duplicated between them, so that I don't have to duplicate my code. (There are other directives in the file that are related to a CMS system, and those are working as expected.)

On the current Apache 2.2 server, everything works fine. My client's webhost wants to upgrade to a server with Apache 2.4, and on the test server the rewrite rule fails. Instead of loading the page, it just displays "File not found."

All other rules are executed as expected, it's just that one that fails. I have tried adding/removing `/` characters and removing `[L]` from the rule, it always fails. I tried adding `[R]` to send the redirect to the browser, but even that failed. But if I change the url to the same filename but in the `members` directory, then the file loads successfully.

Being able to change one directory name to another seems like a pretty basic function of mod_rewrite. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have access to Apache configuration files, maybe mod_rewrite is not enabled?

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Make sure also that `AllowOverride` is set to `All` (or at least `FileInfo`). In 2.4 default value of AllowOverride is `None`, in 2.2 it was `All`)